# How Can I Reload Jquery After Browser Re-size?

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I have a simple jquery snippet to load a div after another:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $(".mob-nav").insertAfter(".primary-nav");
})
```

I’ve noticed that when the browser is re-sized it reverts the div’s to their original position so would like to re-load the above jquery snippet on browser re-size. I’ve tried:

```
$Query(window).resize( function() {

$(".mob-nav").insertAfter(".primary-nav");

});
```

And:

```
window.onresize = function(event) {

    $(".mob-nav").insertAfter(".primary-nav");

}
```

But neither seem to work.

Comment: In your first code snidbit you use `jQuery`, in your second you are using `$Query` most likely `$Query` needs to be changed to `jQuery` if your first bit of code is working

Answer (score 0):

First, define a function to insert `.mob-nav` after `.primary-nav`.

```
function setupNav() {
    $(".mob-nav").insertAfter(".primary-nav");
}
```

Then you can add event listeners on page load and window resize using that function.

```
$(setupNav);
$(window).resize(setupNav);
```

Comment: Thanks for the snippet. So for a JQuery newb how would this be structured?

Answer (score 0):

Resizing the browser window does not in itself move `<div>` elements to other locations in the DOM (ie. it will not "physically" relocate the `<div>` back to where it was when the page loaded). That is of course unless you have *more* javascript somewhere else that is causing it, in which case I would recommend finding that script and fixing it instead.

Resizing might, however, have an effect on the visual appearance of the `<div>`, depending on your CSS (especially media queries, if you are using them). If the issue is related to CSS, then jQuery is probably not where you want to handle the issue - you will need to find the troublesome CSS and fix it.

I will point out that you have a typo in your question. The first example of what you tried should be:

```
jQuery(window).resize( function() {
    $(".mob-nav").insertAfter(".primary-nav");
});
```

That may fix your issue, however I highly recommend that you look into any CSS-related problems because from your question itself it doesn't sound like this would actually be the correct resolution.

Answer (score 0):

You need a debounce... Underscore has a really nice one...
the resize method returns too many callbacks, too quick... you can see that in your console if you try this.

**you can see that behavior here:** 
https://jsfiddle.net/leojavier/35zhogh4/

```
var i = 0;
$(window).resize(function(){
console.log(i);
    i++
});
```

**this is the behavior with the debouncer:** https://jsfiddle.net/leojavier/xjj3os8d/

```
var i = 0;
var lazyLayout = _.debounce(message, 300);

function message(){
 console.log(i);
    i++;
}
$(window).resize(function(){lazyLayout()});
```

**To add the DIVs just append the elements to the parent:**
https://jsfiddle.net/leojavier/35zhogh4/1/

```
<button>add Element</button>
<section class="container"></section>
```

JS

```
var html = '<div></div>';
$('button').on('click', function(){
    $('.container').append(html)
})
```

css

```
div{
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
    border:thin solid #CCC;
    margin:5px;
    display:inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved by wrapping in jQuery(document).ready(function($){

Here's the snippet that works:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
  $(window).resize(function(){
       $(".mob-nav").insertAfter(".primary-nav");
  });
});
```